# Dialogflow @sys.phone-number slot failing 90% of the time

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a voice commerce action for a big food chain and we expect to receive a massive load of orders via voice. The problem is that we haven't be able to figure out a safe way to capture the user's phone. We are currently trying with sys.phone-number and sys.any but it get the number wrong 90% of the time.

This solution is being deployed to Brazil with local number format xx-xxxxxxxx (2 numbers followed by 9 numbers - 0 to 9)

Answer (score 2):

You may take the help of Regex. You can set a pattern and in the webhook check if the number matches your requirement else ask for input again.For example for a Bangladeshi contact number i have used my own custom entity using regex:

```
(01[3456789])(\d{8})
```

you can follow this [example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-regex-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)